# Viewing Logs in Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

We're having some queries in an Azure SQL database that are occasionally running very slowly.  The issue has been difficult to properly diagnose, as the same queries will run fine at other times, even when the server is under a similar load.

To help, I'd like to be able to view log information for the server.  If I could see a list of transactions, by time, and their outcome (completed, terminated/rolled back, etc) I believe it would be helpful.  Several other SQL pages seem to allude to log-files you can access, but since this is an Azure SQL instance, there isn't a physical server I can just download a file from.

I know I can query sys.event_log to see when particular events are occurring (and in fact, I do see a high amount of deadlocks around our problem times), but I'm unaware of any way to see what query's were being handled at the time of these locks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to view log information for the server. If I could see a list of transactions, by time, and their outcome (completed, terminated/rolled back, etc) I believe it would be helpful.

The log information  you are trying to view is not helpfull.

You can view slowly running queries running using the same manner like on premises [using DMV's](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/sql-database-monitoring-with-dmvs/)

You can also enable [query store](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/query-store-a-flight-data-recorder-for-your-database/) ,which can you show you different stages of query .This i think will help you more in troubleshooting slow queries and is not tied to Premium Databases only